# PHP code is displayed instead of the output

Tags: php

Can someone please explain this code, i am following a very good book that was recommended to me and I have typed the code exactly as it is in the book. it displays the code instead of out, I am not sure what is wrong, the code is from a book called php solutions

```
          <?php
                     // set the max upload size in bytes
                      $max = 51200;
                     if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

                // define the path to the upload folder
                $destination = 'C:\upload_test';
                 // move the file to the uplaod folder and rename it
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']
                    ['tmp_name'],     $destination.$_FILES['image']['setara']);

                    }
                    ?>







    <!doctype html>
    <html  lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mult</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>





    <form action="" method="post" enctype="mutipar/form-data" id="uploadImage">
        <p>
            <label for="image">Upload image:</label>
            <input type="hidden"name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max; ?>">

            <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload">
        </p>
    </form>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is file's extension is `.html` or `.htm`?

Comment: @ClarksonJey isnt both are same ?

Comment: how you are running file and what is file extension ?

Comment: Are you doing that on a server with php instaleled?

Comment: @NullPointer Yep, I want to know that file was maden as whether `.php` or not.

Comment: and have you managed to run any php on this server before? It seems that the file is not parsed as php at all. So the problem is probably not in your code but in the server config

Comment: yes of-course everything else works fine

Comment: @FirstNameereEr Ok can you tell us exactly what's the output, and what's the URL in the browser's address bar ?

Comment: http://localhost/file_uploads/file_upload.php  the output is the code nothing else

Answer (score 2):

This is surely because you are writing PHP code in .html or .htm extension file try putting the code with .php extension file. It will resolve error.

Comment: This answer isn't based on any facts, there may be more options to cause this failure. For example: PHP not installed/enabled, if the OP dragged the file directly in the browser it will also fail etc etc... Please post this as a comment next time.