# My PHP file gives code instead of output

Tags: php, apache, text, output, easyphp

I've already tried the advice given on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315182/php-code-display-the-code-instead-of-output), by opening my .php page with Chrome, Mozilla, and IE (instead of dragging it to them), my EasyPHP is started (along with the other services I just installed with it), my files are located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot (on Vista), and so far, no PHP is being outputted.  It either shows up as code on the page, or it doesn't work at all (includes don't work, for example).  I tried configuring the DirectoryRoot in the httpd.config file (I commented out the original first, instead of deleting it), so it would point to the wwwroot directory, but that didn't work either.  I am very new to EasyPHP and it's been a few years since I really dealt with regular PHP, Apache, and MySQL, so I'm grasping at straws here.

The code in my .htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><html><head>
<title>MySite</title><link href="MySite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>

<body>

<?php
include("topbar.php");
?>

<div id="content">
<h2>Content Goes Here</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code in my topbar.php file:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="container"><div id="header">';
echo '<h1>This is the header.</h1><p class="description">';
echo 'Usually some sort of tagline or description is placed here.</p></div>';
?>
```

I don't know.  I've been searching all over the PHP main site, as well as a few random pages that came up when I used my search engine...  I've gone through the EasyPHP FAQ page, and I haven't yet found an answer the would point me in the right direction.  Other than attempting to edit the httpd.config file, I haven't gone through any other files created by EasyPHP, mainly because I wouldn't know which ones to try editing, nor which lines, or with what.  I just installed EasyPHP last night.  I'm glad for any assistance anyone can provide in plain English (please, no one try to show off how cool you are with all your fancy technobabble that I'd have to get out a tech dictionary for, or lengthy examples that would be hard for a newb to read, thanks).

Comment: What are you seeing as an output? Usually you need to have a `.php` extension to process PHP directives in HTML.

Comment: Both files only recognize the HTML portions.  The .htm file outputs:

Content goes here.

The .php file outputs:

<?php
echo '<div id="container"><div id="header">';
echo '<h1>This is the header.</h1><p class="description">';
echo 'Usually some sort of tagline or description is placed here.</p></div>';
echo 'Hello World';
?>

Comment: Also, I just noticed this closed (???WHY???) link and it seems to at least point me in a good direction.  I don't know how to make this resolution happen though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996031/easy-php-displays-php-code-instead-of-processing?rq=1

Comment: Hey, I'm still lost in this situation.  Do you have any ideas on how to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

Web server will not process PHP code written in file extension other than .php. Try changing file extension to .php instead of .html.

You can use HTML tags within .php file.

Comment: Zeeshan Elahi:

It's already been stated on the page I liked to in my question that this is a non-factual answer and that there are a lot of other reasons for why this happens.  And, I had already tried that before I came here anyway.  It doesn't work.  Please don't spam my question, thanks.